# how to make sure hosts do not get picked unless specified in Ansible run command

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a use case, where I don't want the particular host to be selected by playbook run unless explicitly specified.

```
[webapp]
host1
host2
host3 <-new node
```

host3 is new host and i don't want it to get accidentally added in nginx upstream but I want to setup my web app (install my app, setup iptables etc.) on host3. One solution, I can think of is add some property to that host and skip such hosts from nginx conf template. But this has to be done in every part of my ansible tasks where i dont want host where appsetup is pending.

Is there an inbuilt way by which hosts can only be selected by ansible playbook runs when explicitly specified?

Answer (score 0):

there might be some hacky ways to do it but i don't suggest that. why dont you put host3 in a separate group?

alternatively, you can set a host level boolean flag like below:

```
[webapp]
host1 fully_install=true
host2 fully_install=true
host3 fully_install=false
```

and then you can run your tasks by checking that boolean flag if it is true. but in my opinion, it is a little bit over-engineered solution.